# Simplify $(-1)^{n-1}\frac{800}{(\pi^2){(2n-1)^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im having problems simplifying this equation, I know that the answer should be $$\frac{800}{(\pi^2)}\cdot \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^2}$$ however I'm not entirely sure why.. If someone could explain it would be a great help

Comment: I don't get it. You mention an expression, and then you say "I know that the answer should be .. " ... and then the same expression. Did you accidentally write the same expression twice or did I not understand the question?

Comment: Also, if the problem is just simplifying the given expression, I would say that it's already in its simplest form.

Comment: Where is the equation?

Comment: @MattiP., someone edited the title to make it identical with the expression in the text. However, the only differences in the original were the order of the terms and the power of $-1$, which was $n-1$ in the title instead of $n+1$. (If those differences are what the OP finds puzzling, the commutative law for multiplication accounts for the reordering of the terms, and $$(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{(n-1)+2}=(-1)^2(-1)^{n-1}=1(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}$$ accounts for the change from $n-1$ to $n+1$.)

Comment: As written it is unclear what you are asking. For the reasons listed by Matti P. I hazard a guess that may be you are to sum those number from $n=1$ to $\infty$. But, then it would no longer be about [tag:algebra-precalculus]!?

Comment: I decided to edit the title back to its original appearance (but in built-up fraction form). It's possible that "simplify" here simply means pulling all the constant stuff out front and collecting the terms with $n$'s.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are two questions here:

The mathematical question 'why is $(-1)^{n-1}$ equal to $(-1)^{n+1}$?'

and the aesthetic question 'why is the expression with all constants (numbers) in one fraction on the left and all stuff that depends on $n$ together in another fraction on the right considered simpler than the original form?'

The mathematical question has been answered in the comments. As for the aesthetic question: of course this is subjective, but the form with constants separated from the rest helps see the structure. For instance in some computations you can help yourself by 'summarizing' the entire term $\frac{800}{\pi^2}$ as $C$ (or some other letter of your choice) so that it won't distract and initimidate you as much when you continue to do stuff with the rest of the equation. Another example of a context where the simplification would be useful: if this were one term in an infinite sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{800}{\pi^2} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n - 1)^2}$$ as suggested in the comments, then a next simplifying step could be to rewrite the entire sum as:

$$\frac{800}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n - 1)^2}$$

And this further simplification would be harder to see if you had not did the previous simplification (of changing the expression in the title to the one in the post).